# Remove spaces from HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, expression

I am using Google translator API. I am sending html string. The translation works fine but the tags are getting messed up.

For example:

```
<b>Hello World</b>
```

becomes

```
<b>Hello World</ b>
```

Sometimes tags are returned like:

```
<b>Hello World< / b >
```

My effort in PHP (that doesn't work)

```
preg_replace('~<(\s*)/(.*)(\s*)>~is', '</$2>', $string);
```

Comment: Why do you care? That's valid HTML.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, no `< / b >` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$string = preg_replace(',<\s*/\s*(\w+)\s*>,s', '</$1>', $string);
```

Comment: @FlipBooth, you're welcome. And here at SO you can thank with the vote buttons. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, regex will solve this exact problem. But only protects against the spaces in tags. Won't protect you from further HTML issues.

This will only work so far, but you could try an HTML parser like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which has some handling of invalid HTML. Then you could get cleaned up HTML out of the library.

Comment: Just wanting you to be aware that Google could change their API response at any time rendering your "fix" useless. You aren't fixing the root problem with a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
preg_replace('/<\s*\/\s*([^\s]*?)\s*>/', '</\\1>', $string);
```

Live demo: http://regexr.com?3444s